# HTML how to set table width in px

Tags: html, css, angular

This may be a dumb question but I'm unable to set width with a certain amount of pixel to my table rows.

I'm using angular and calculating the cell width at the view initialization (and give me a number of 275px per column).

So I set this to my th in the table like this: `[style.width]="cellWidth + 'px'"`
And the style is applicated since I found this on my th elements:

```
element.style {
    width: 275px;
}
```

But my table is not all in 275px, the first column is 274px and the third one is 276px.. why remove a pixel from one column to add it to another one?

And when I change the width of my window I have the same problem, I always have 1 or 2px of difference between my columns.

How can I have a fixed width ?

Comment: Tables use widths as rough guidelines rather than hard requirements. My guess is that some of the content is 276px wide, and then the table refuses to make that column less than 276px, since the content wouldn't fit otherwise! Similarly, if the maximum available width is less than the widths you assign, it may make columns with less content narrower, to avoid horizontal scrolling.

Comment: But that's just a guess; I can't say anything definitive until I see the full code.

Comment: My content is set to the width I compute (275px) so this is why I found this strange, I'll try with divs instead of a table

Comment: Might be a border.

Answer (score 1):

If the content is less than 275px the problem is related to padding(your content will be width + 2*padding): table, th, tr have a default padding.
If you want really 275px you should also use min-width not width.

Css

```
table, th, td {
  padding:0;
}
```

Html

```
<table >
  <tr>
    <th [style.minWidth]="cellWidth + 'px'">Company</th>
    <th [style.minWidth]="cellWidth + 'px'">Contact</th>
    <th [style.minWidth]="cellWidth + 'px'">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

TS

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  cellWidth=275;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h9abbu

Comment: So what should I do If I need border and padding?

Comment: No problem, just remember this when you are setting the width, if you use 1px each side the size will be 277px(or use 273px to keep the size 275px). The behavior is the same with min-wdth.

Comment: Even with no padding I still have my issue, the screen width is 1823px which give me a width of 260.4 (divided by 7), but I still have cells with width 260px and others with 261px

Comment: Does it happens in all browsers?